# Cordova app working fine on emulator but not on device

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am creating a Phonegap application that uses the Cordova camera functionality. When I run it on the ios emulator the photo gallery popover works great, however while running on my iPad Air 64bit retina it doesn't work at all. Any idea why?

```
$(document).on("tap", "#place-camera-roll", function() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, {
        destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType:Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    });

    function cameraSuccess(imageData) {
        alert(imageData);
    }

    function cameraError() {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            "Sorry... There was an error accessing your photos.",
            null,
            "Error",
            "Done"
        );
    }
});
```

Edit: I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I tap. code=1,address=0x3000300030001